# Can use DTOs when configuring Security in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dto

I have a service, that fetches objects from repository and always returns them as DTOs (mapping framework was used). I also have implementation of UserDetailsService which uses my original service to get User entities. In the end it gets only DTOs. For now it works fine, but since it is still service layer, shouldn't it be entity instead of DTO? Can it backfire sometime later?

Comment: Services that contain business logic shouldn't know anything about DTOs. The mapping should always be done outside any service layer :)

Comment: @Vaelyr so is it ok if i have two services: one for fetching data from repository and convert them using mapper methods and the other for bussiness logic? And for example make methods of the 1st one package-private so other services can access entities as well as DTOs?

Comment: You don't really want repository to deal with mapping, leave that as close to the representation layer as possible. Same goes for services, ideally you would never want any service package to have any DTO package imports. In short, service/business layer only deals with entities or data structures in some cases (not DTOs specifically). It would be more clear if you could show simple example of your UserDetailsService and some related code.

Comment: @Vaelyr ok, to clear things out: 
I have DB -> JPA repository (which returns entities) -> service layer which performs business operation and calls method of mapper (automatically generated) to return DTOs. My question is: should I include all business logic, entities fetching (from repository) and returning DTO directly to Controllers in single service (for example UserService deals with all stuff related to users).

Comment: Leave the mapper part purely for controllers. Fetching and business logic lives in services and they also return entities. Let controllers do the mapping with the result from the service.